# Compare two files(file1 & file2) and add one column from from file2 to file1 if first column of two files matches

Tags: shell, awk

I have two files (file1 and file2)

file1

```
ABC=14.2.0.7.SAMPLE=git.xyz/plugins/gitiles/+/refs/heads/clientpatch/abc/patch142007
DEF=14.3.0.5.SAMPLE=git.xyz/plugins/gitiles/+/refs/heads/clientpatch/def/patch143005
DEF=14.3.0.5.SAMPLE2=git.calypso/plugins/gitiles/+/refs/heads/clientpatch/def/patch14300-calib
HIJ=12.0.0.0.Sp3.SAMPLE3=git.xyz/plugins/gitiles/+/refs/heads/clientpatch/hij/patch120000sp3
MNO=16.1.0.28.SAMPLE=git.xyz/plugins/gitiles/+/refs/heads/clientpatch/mno/patch161028
```

.......(150 lines)

file2

```
IJK = open 
ABC = closed 
PQR = closed 
DEF = open 
HIJ = open 
LMN = closed
MNO = closed 
PQR = open
```

......(> 150 lines)

output file

```
ABC=14.2.0.7.SAMPLE=git.xyz/plugins/gitiles/+/refs/heads/client/abc/patch142007=closed
DEF=14.3.0.5.SAMPLE=git.xyz/plugins/gitiles/+/refs/heads/client/def/patch143005=open
DEF=14.3.0.5.SAMPLE2=git.xyz/plugins/gitiles/+/refs/heads/client/def/patch14300-calib=open
HIJ=12.0.0.0.Sp3.SAMPLE3=git.xyz/plugins/gitiles/+/refs/heads/client/hij/patch120000sp3=open
MNO=16.1.0.28.SAMPLE=git.xyz/plugins/gitiles/+/refs/heads/client/mno/patch161028=closed
```

I have tried the following script. But it is not giving me any output. Not even printing anything. No errors

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
key1=`echo $line | awk -F "=" '{print $1}'` < file1
key2=`echo $line | awk -F "=" '{print $2}'` < file1 
key3=`echo $line | awk -F "=" '{print $3}'` < file1 
key4=`echo $line | awk -F "=" '{print $1}'` < file2   
value3=`echo $line | awk -F "=" '{print $2}'` < file2   
if [ "$key1" == "$key4" ]; then   
echo "$key1=$key2=$key3=$value3"   
fi   
done
```

Giving a brief description for how the code should work.

The code should compare first columns of two files(file1 and file2). If each name matches it should give me output file as listed above. Else go to the next line. I should get output if my two files are either in sorted or unsorted format. 
Helps will be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or another approach with `awk` that stores the `file2` values in an array and then appends the correct state to the appropriate line in `file1`:

```
awk -F' = ' 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} {print $0"="a[$1]}' file2 FS="=" file1
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ awk -F' = ' 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} {print $0"="a[$1]}' file2 FS="=" file1
ABC=14.2.0.7.SAMPLE=git.xyz/plugins/gitiles/+/refs/heads/clientpatch/abc/patch142007=closed
DEF=14.3.0.5.SAMPLE=git.xyz/plugins/gitiles/+/refs/heads/clientpatch/def/patch143005=open
DEF=14.3.0.5.SAMPLE2=git.calypso/plugins/gitiles/+/refs/heads/clientpatch/def/patch14300-calib=open
HIJ=12.0.0.0.Sp3.SAMPLE3=git.xyz/plugins/gitiles/+/refs/heads/clientpatch/hij/patch120000sp3=open
MNO=16.1.0.28.SAMPLE=git.xyz/plugins/gitiles/+/refs/heads/clientpatch/mno/patch161028=closed
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply David. For this one also Iam getting the output as I wanted

Comment: Yes, there are a couple of ways to skin this cat, here, we just use `split` to grab the 1st field in the `file1` values and use that to append the `open/closed` already stored in array `a`. I like both solution actually `:)`

Comment: `NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2; next} {foo}` would be more idiomatic than `NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2} NR>FNR {foo}'`. Also if you used `-F' ?= ?'` then you wouldn't need to `split()` and `b[1]` since $1 would be populated as you want.

Comment: Thank you Ed, but wouldn't `-F "?=?"` result in loss of a character in each field for `file1`? Incorporating the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  OFS="="
}
FNR==NR{
  a[$1]=$NF
  next
}
($1 in a){
  print $0,a[$1]
}
'   Input_file2  FS="="  Input_file1
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                   ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{                  ##Starting BEGIN section from here.
  OFS="="               ##Setting OFS as = here for all lines.
}
FNR==NR{                ##Checking condition if FNR==NR which will be TRUE when file2 is being read.
  a[$1]=$NF             ##Creating an array a with index $1 and value is last field.
  next                  ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
($1 in a){              ##Checking condition if $1 of current line is present in array a then do following.
  print $0,a[$1]        ##Printing current line and value of array a with index $1.
}
'  file2 FS="=" file1   ##Mentioning Input_file file2 and file1 and setting FS="=" for file1 here.
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response RavinderSingh. Iam getting the output as I wanted.

Comment: @RupeshMadhav, Your welcome, I have also added detailed explanation for my code too now, cheers

Comment: Hello RavinderSingh, your command for the above question is not printing every lines in my file. Just consider file1 has 150 lines. It is printing only less than 50 lines. If the second column in file2 contains two words, it is printing only the second word. Can u suggest another command

Comment: @RupeshMadhav, Could you please open a new thread for same? Its always advisable to ask one question per thread only and changing or adding to your question now may need to change code completely, so IMHO if you could open a new question that will be great then.